How to use static route to connect 2 routers?
I have 1 router (R1) connected to the internet which has LAN IP 192.168.10.1 and Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0
I have another router (R2) which is connected to 1 LAN port of R1 and to the WAN port of R2. This router has LAN IP 192.168.0.1 and Subnet Mask 255.255.255.0 and WAN IP: 192.168.10.200 (static)
My goal is to get the LAN network of R2 to be accessible to R1 LAN (R2 devices can already access R1 but not the other way). The goal here is to be able to be connected to R1 and access a Raspberry Pi connected to R2 localy and expose devices to the Raspberry Pi that are connected to R1. From what I've read online, static routing is what I need.
What am I supposed to enter in Destination IP, Subnet Mask, Gateway in the Static Routing Table of the 3 routers so that I can make this connection possible ?
The reason I am not using and AP or bypassing this device is that my R1 router is my ISP and the R2 is going to be my wireless point (disabling my R1 wifi) and at the same time giving me more control over DHCP reserve list since my ISP router (R1) has a limit of 8 reserved dhcp ip devices (very weird but confirmed by the ISP.
Edit:
ISP (R1) - Dasan H660GM
R2 - Tp Link Archer C50

If R2 is connected to R1, then R2 already has a route to all devices connected to R1. Is there a reason you are creating a second subnet on R2?

Indeed R2 can access R1 devices already, but for example my pc connected to R1 can't connect locally to my Pi on R2, that's what I am struggling with

And the reason for the other subnet is that R2 has its own DHCP in order to give me access to reserve more, since my R1 is limited to 8

Why is a subnet that exists only within your network limited to 8 hosts? /29 is 6 hosts, and /28 is 14 hosts; an 8-host subnet does not make sense. 255.255.255.0 subnet mask is 256 hosts

Anyway, set the DNS of R2 to R1, and you can configure the DNS of R1 to anything you want.  This way a device connected to R2 is connected to R1 through R2. This assumes that R2 can ping R1.

I meant R1 is limited in DHCP reservations, I can only reserve a maximum of 8 ips, my ISP didn't reply on why that's the case.

So the best option is dns R2 to R1 and that way I am able to access devices connected to R1 from R2? Keeping the subnet like it currently is right?

There is no way your router's DHCP is limited to 8 intranet assignments

You are necessarily complicating things and I expect there is some confusion on your part. You are going to have a lot of pain if you take this approach given your current knowledge. You'd be better off setting the modem in pass-through mode if supported and running your network off your second device  please [edit] your question to include the make and model of ISP provided modem/router.

I thought it wouldnt be limited to 8 but it is, everytime I try to add more than 8 it gives me an error stating list is reached the max. After contacting the ISP by phone they stated that it's indeed limited to 8.


What am I supposed to enter in Destination IP, Subnet Mask, Gateway in the Static Routing Table of the 3 routers so that I can make this connection possible ?

"Destination" plus "Subnet mask" is literally the network you want to reach.
"Gateway" is an IP address of the router towards which you want to direct the packets. (Since routers typically have multiple addresses, you need to use the one that's "facing you".)
For example, if R1 wants to reach R2's network 192.168.0.0/24, then the "Destination" is 192.168.0.0 with netmask 255.255.255.0 and the gateway is R2's 'WAN' address 192.168.10.200.
(The gateway can't be R2's 'LAN' address 192.168.0.1 because R1 doesn't know how to reach it yet.)

That was quite helpful, I'm gonna give it a try. Just a quick question, should I put static routes on both of them or just R2 for example? (Destination - 192.168.10.0 / Subnet mask - 255.255.255.0 / Gateway - 192.168.10.1)

R2 doesn't need a static route to R1's network because it is already directly connected to that network (it has an IP address from there, after all), which automatically gives it a 'direct' route to 192.168.10.0/24. Only R1 needs a manual route to R2's network because otherwise it knows nothing about it. (Optionally, PCs on R1 can also have a route to R2's network, bypassing R1 for performance.)

Just 2 more questions, should I turn off the firewall and upnp/NAT on R2? And on R1 what should be the value for the "Metric" field and in the "Interface" field, WAN0 or LAN?

I tried you sudgestion just now and I get 2 type of errors! PC connected to R1 trying to conect to an R2 device by usin the 192.168.10.x I get  ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and if I try to access the R2 router page using the R1 IP 192.168.1.x I get  ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

You should turn off the firewall on R2 or at the very least configure it to allow connections inbound. By default R2 is set up to assume that the 'WAN' interface is in fact a WAN connection so it'll block everything for security. I would also turn off NAT on R2, since it's no longer necessary once routing is in place. The metric is irrelevant as long as there's only one route for the network, and the interface should be whichever leads to the gateway (for R1 that would be "LAN" since that's where R2 is connected).

I have tried it, I can't seem to access anything on R2 from a pc connected on R1. Should I be able to access something from a device connected to R2 using the 193.168.0.x subnet while connected to R1 (that is on the 198.168.10.0)?

Yes, that was the whole point of the thing, wasn't it? Are you able to at least ping R2's own address (192.168.0.1) from the R1 network? Most of the time it's either R2's firewall or sometimes R1's firewall that's the problem. Can you also try adding the route directly on some PC that's on R1?

Yeah I tried adding the route on PC connected to R1, still not abble, Firewalls off everything that should be impeeding the thing from working off and still cant access subnet 192.168.0.1 (I get ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)
